# How do I set up indentation to 2 spaces in web-mode

Tags: web-mode

I just installed web-mode. It works, but the indentation
seems to be set to 4 spaces by default. How does one
properly set it to 2 spaces?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to the [web-mode documentation](http://web-mode.org), you can do that with the following:

```el
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

You can also set values for `web-mode-css-indent-offset` for CSS, and `web-mode-code-indent-offset` Javascript, Java, PHP, etc.

Comment: It might be better to `customize-group` web-mode and set this.

Comment: @ChristianStewart or even better, do it with [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)

Answer (score 14):

With [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package):

```el
(use-package web-mode
  :custom
  (web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (web-mode-code-indent-offset 2))
```