# How to control JavaScript indentation?

Tags: indentation, javascript

I am coding in Node.js, each time I want to write something that looks like this:

```
const product = Factory
  .model('App/Models/Product')
  .create()
```

I get this as an output:

```
const product = Factory
      .model('App/Models/Product')
      .create()
```

[image]

And I delete back the space before the last line, and then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue coding, the last line jumps right again as this screenshot shows:

[image]

Adding `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in my `~/.emacs` file does not help.

What settings should I add for my Emacs to avoid this?

Comment: Which mode are you using? Is it `js-mode`, `js2-mode`, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am using `js2-mode`

Comment: Indentation in `js2-mode` is controlled by `js-mode`, and it seems that I can't get it to not give special indentation to chained calls. Maybe someone reported a problem with this before to either `js-mode` or `js2-mode` maintainers.

Comment: Interesting feedback, thank you, I will investigate more about it

Comment: try changing indent level in C-h v js-chain-indent

Comment: Thank you, I am going to document about `js-chain-indent` @A_P

Comment: @Begueradj ahhh, I just tried it. changing chain indent does not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simpler than i thought. I use the same solution I used here and it worked: [How do I set up indentation to 2 spaces in web-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/25044/how-do-i-set-up-indentation-to-2-spaces-in-web-mode/47272#47272)